# Mysql, Access and Oracle package

Tags: java

i'm starting to learn Java. When I was learning PHP I used EasyPHP WAMP on my computer so I had PHP, MYSQL and Apache all in one package. Is there a similar package like this for Java, Access and Oracle?

Thanks

John

Comment: `Java` has `JDBC` Java DataBase Connectivity for connecting with different databases.

Comment: are you learning core java or advanced java(for web development)?

Answer (score 0):

Taking EasyPHP as example I guess for `Java` you are looking for IDE like 
**Netbeans**

 **Eclipse**

**JDeveloper**